# Parsec - improving error message for "between"

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm learning Parsec. I've got this code:

```
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (many)

inBracketsP :: Parser [String]
inBracketsP = (many $ between (char '[') (char ']') (many $ char '.')) <* eof

main :: IO ()
main =  putStr $ show $ parse inBracketsP "" "[...][..."
```

The result is

```
Left (line 1, column 10):
unexpected end of input
expecting "." or "]"
```

This message is not useful (adding `.` won't fix the problem). I'd expect something like `']' expected` (only `]` fixes the problem).

Is it possible to achieve that easily with Parsec? I've seen the SO question [Parsec: error message at specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964405/parsec-error-message-at-specific-location), which is inspiring, but I'd prefer to stick to the `between` combinator, without manual lookahead or other overengineering (kind of), if possible.

Comment: But there's no rule that there's a maximum of 3 dots, so another `.` could go there.

Comment: Yes, another dot would be parsed (hence the default error message). However, I want the parse error to indicate the missing closing token, not to list everything that would be parsed (a lot of things in case of a more complicated grammar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide a terminal from being displayed in the expected input list by attaching an empty label to it (`parser <?> ""`):

```hs
inBracketsP :: Parser [String]
inBracketsP = (many $ between (char '[') (char ']') (many $ (char '.' <?> ""))) <* eof

-- >>> main
-- Left (line 1, column 10):
-- unexpected end of input
-- expecting "]"
```

In `megaparsec`, there is also a [`hidden` combinator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#v:hidden) that achieves the same effect.